# Is there a way of changing the useContext value in a child so the other childs get that changed value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

That's basically it, is there a way of having a parent that creates a context with a default value (null for example) and then modify that value in one of the child components so when another child uses that context it is now changed to that value?

E.g: We have an `App.jsx` file that creates a `userContext` and wraps the app with it, then in a `Login.jsx` file component we change that `userContext` to an actual user (as If we were logging in) and then in a `Dashboard.jsx` file, we view that user's data (as If he had logged in).

I have this question because I have tried just this and the `Dashboard.jsx` component just gets the `userContext` from the `App.jsx` file, instead of that context but with the user data, changed in `Login.jsx`

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd need to see more code to have a better idea what's actually going on - talk of "changing" the context has me a bit worried that you're trying to mutate values (which you shouldn't do). The way to make `useContext` return different values in different subtrees of your app is to have a new context provider component wrapping any part which should have its own context value.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up your context as modifiable state value. Here we set up a context object with a `user` and `setUser` value. We can then call `setUser` from the login page to update the context value.

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const context = useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user]);
  return <context.Provider value={context}>...</context.Provider>
}

export const Login = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(UserContext);
  // do this as appropriate in a useEffect or whatever
  // this will update the root context's value
  ctx.setUser(someUser);
}
```